# Left Join con condición que devuelva campos NULL si no hay coincidencia

Tags: mysql, sql

Intento hacer un `select` que me devuelva `TODOS` los cursos de la tabla curso, y además, si el email `1234` tiene algún registro en `fkidcurso`, se muestre el valor de `progreso`, es decir, si `progreso` está vacío lo mostrará igualmente, pero vacío.

Esta consulta me devolvería todos los registros:

```
SELECT * FROM Curso, usuarioCurso WHERE fkidcurso = id
```

Si filtro por `fkidcurso`, entonces no me devuelve todos los registros de curso ya que no tienen el mail asociado.

```
SELECT * FROM Curso, usuarioCurso WHERE fkidcurso = id AND email = '$email'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDITO:
El left join no devuelve el registro correspondiente al "curso basico" (id

**SELECT * FROM Curso LEFT JOIN usuarioCurso ON fkidcurso = id WHERE email = 1234'**

Comment: Has intentado utilizar LEFT JOIN?

Comment: El left join no devuelve el registro correspondiente al "curso basico" (id 

**SELECT * FROM Curso LEFT JOIN usuarioCurso ON fkidcurso = id WHERE email = 1234'**

Comment: Tal vez: `SELECT * FROM  Curso AS C   LEFT JOIN usuarioCurso AS UC ON(C.id = UC.fkidcurso AND EMAIL='1234')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que quieres mostrar registros de la tabla del `JOIN` cuando no hay coincidencias en ella.

Para eso tienes que usar `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` o `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, lo que cambia es el orden en que pongas las tablas.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarioCurso uc
RIGHT OUTER JOIN  Curso c ON (c.id = uc.fkidcurso AND email='1234');
```

**Salida:**

```
usuario_id  fkidcurso   email   progreso    id  titulo              resumen
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           1           1234    1           1   Principios básicos  En este curso aprenderás
NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL        2   Curso básico        Este es el curso básico
```

O bien:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Curso c
LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarioCurso uc ON (c.id = uc.fkidcurso AND email='1234');
```

**Salida:**

```
id  titulo              resumen                     usuario_id     fkidcurso    email   progreso
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Principios básicos  En este curso aprenderás    1              1            1234    1
2   Curso básico        Este es el curso básico     NULL           NULL         NULL    NULL
```

---

#### Fiddle

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[`DEMOSTRACIÓN`](https://rextester.com/DNW97180)**</kbd> y hacer pruebas sobre ella.

Comment: gracias. Esto solucionó mi problema

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscar realizar se puede hacer utilizando **LEFT JOIN** pero en el `where` debes buscar mostrar registros cuando email sea `NULL`.

Te comparto un código de ejemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  Curso AS C
  LEFT JOIN usuarioCurso AS UC ON(C.id = UC.fkidcurso)
WHERE
  email = '$email'
  OR email IS NULL
```

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM
  Curso AS C
  LEFT JOIN usuarioCurso AS UC ON(C.id = UC.fkidcurso)
WHERE
  email = '1234'
  OR email IS NULL

Esta consulta devuelve lo mismo que la anterior, es decir, no devuelve ningún registro con el curso 2

Comment: Hmmm, raro. Prueba así: `SELECT * FROM Curso AS C LEFT JOIN usuarioCurso AS UC ON(C.id = UC.fkidcurso) WHERE email = '1234' OR email = 'NULL'`

Comment: mismo resultado

Comment: Está raro, yo acabo de realizar una prueba y funciona bien. En la imagen puedes ver que en la última consulta devuelve los dos registros: https://ibb.co/gVy53qq

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero no funciona, ya que tu consulta devuelve valores null: en tu consulta estás definiendo el valor NULL para el campo fkidcurso en tu primera tabla, cuando realmente el campo fkidcurso no debería existir en esa primera tabla, ya que id es la clave primaria. Por esto a ti te devuelve los resultados null, ya los has definido e introducido como null en un insert previamente